# Error caused by merging two tables in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, primary-key

I want to merge two tables in one I have all clients with important metrics and in the second client_id with emails of clients. I was trying to do with this:

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.merge(allclients, dataframe2[['owner_email','trk_hs_owner']], on='client_id')
```

I got error with client_id and I don't know what could cause this.

Comment: Just a wild guess because you failed to show the dataframes and the *full* error message including the stacktrace, but one of the dataframes probably has no `client_id` column.

Comment: both has client_id

Comment: dataframe2.columns
Index(['client_id', 'owner_email', 'trk_hs_owner'], dtype='object')
mns
allclients.columns
Index(['date', 'client_id', 'impressions', 'visits', 'conversions', 'clicks'...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are merging `allclients` that certainly has a `client_id` column with `dataframe2[['owner_email','trk_hs_owner']]` that cannot: you sliced it to only 2 columns `'owner_email'`,`'trk_hs_owner'`.

You should use:

```
result = pd.merge(allclients, dataframe2[['client_id','owner_email','trk_hs_owner']],
                  on='client_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

dataframe2 doesn't contain client_id column.If client_id column is there in dataframe2 you need to select that as well and if it is present with some different name then you need to specify left and right column name.
Two possible solutions are:

If column name is same in both table:

```
pd.merge(allclients, dataframe2[['client_id','owner_email','trk_hs_owner']], on='client_id')
```

If column name is different in both table:

```
pd.merge(allclients, dataframe2[['diff_col_name','owner_email','trk_hs_owner']],left_on='client_id',right_on='diff_col_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

this statement selects only two columns of dataframe2:

```
dataframe2[['owner_email','trk_hs_owner']]
```

This drops the client_id column. Hence, you cannot join on client_id after.

Try:

```
pd.merge(allclients, dataframe2[['owner_email','trk_hs_owner', 'client_id']], on='client_id')
```